# Clicking a popover scrolls back to top of the page [Bootstrap and Django]

Tags: jquery, django, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap with Django and so far everything as worked. However, I am trying to use the popover functionality, and I keep running into a problem. Whenever a click my popover, the page scrolls back to the top... BUT the popover do appear. here is my code:

```
//////////<..... a lot more HTML ....>//////////
<div class="bs-docs-example">
<a href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-danger" rel="popover" title="A Title" id="testpop" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. right?">Click to toggle popover</a>
</div>
{% endblock %}


{% block js %}
{{ block.super }}

{% bootstrap_javascript_tag "modal" %}
{% bootstrap_javascript_tag "alert" %}
{% bootstrap_javascript_tag "tooltip" %}
{% bootstrap_javascript_tag "popover" %}

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#testpop").popover();
</script>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You need to prevent the default event action in the `popover()` handler.  E.g. `$('#testpop').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); ... });`

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13755033/how-to-fix-scrolling-with-twitter-bootstrap-and-popover.  Even though this question was asked first, that one seems to have a more complete answer.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can solve that by preventing the default action of the anchor element:

```
$('a#testpop').on('click', function(e) {e.preventDefault(); return true;});
```

Comment: sadly none of the solutions in this answer worked for me. Popover not only scrolls the page for me but also killes other anchors behaviors as well as the jquery-ui datepicker. :( Any ideas?

Comment: As mentioned above, you might check this related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13759775/931277  They suggest using a div instead of an anchor, which may help. In your case it sounds like the selector you're using to add the popover behavior might not be specific enough. It's probably worth opening a new question specific to your case, and posting some code.

Comment: Found and solved other issues with popover except the last one regarding it autoscrolling up to the page. I tried every single solution found in SO as well as some others more to no avail. Will need to post a new question :(

Answer (score 34):

You can add href="javascript://" to the anchor tag.

Comment: So simple! And no change to URL in the browser.

Answer (score 30):

Remove the **href="#"** tag, it should work.

Comment: Just as a note, according to the Bootstrap docs, you shouldn't do this if you're if you're using a dismissible popover.

Comment: @Knyght - With version 3 you can remove the `href` but you need to add some other attributes. See the docs for [Dismiss on next click](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dismiss-on-next-click).

Comment: This disabled the popover altogether for me (bootstrap 4)

Answer (score 3):

This can also be cause by having an element with `autofocus=on` within the popover (tested in chrome)

Comment: This helped me narrow down that my customer popover component was setting the focus of an input element inside the popover. That was causing the scroll.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `href="#..."` with `data-target="#..."`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Bootstrap 2.3.2

The point is not about clicking. Even if I call show popover programatically, it scrolls me up to the top.

The point is on bootstrap tooltip show function. There is a line there:

`$tip.detach().css({ top: 0, left: 0, display: 'block' })`

It applies the display block when detaching tip just to get its height and width. This is a metaphysical question! Invisible elements do not have a height!! To fix this I commented that line and added:

```
$tip.show();
```

Just after the line where it gets a position:

```
pos = this.getPosition()
```

It worked to me.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem with Bootstrap v3.3.2 and solved it by using buttons instead of anchor tags.

I then went back to [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers)  and found that all but one of the popover examples given there use buttons - and surprise surprise - the one that does use the anchor leaves out the href attribute!

Answer (score 0):

just add `onclick="return false;"` to Anchor element