# How to fix scrolling with twitter-bootstrap and popover?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I am using twitter-bootstrap and popovers.

I am facing the following problem: when the user clicks on a link that opens a popover at the bottom of the page, it scrolls all the way to top of the page first.  This requires the user to scroll back down to see the popover open.  In the demos on the twitter-bootstrap site, I don't see this and was wondering if I could get help on this issue.

```
<div class="span1" style=" width: 60px; ">
    <a href="#" class="example2" rel="popover" data-html="true" data-placement="left" data-content="&lt;a href = '/social/2lPdXV1KO4s/Bhangra indian Jingle Bells balle balle Merry Christmas'&gt;&lt;img src='http://i4.ytimg.com/vi/2lPdXV1KO4s/hqdefault.jpg'&gt;&lt;/a&gt;" data-original-title="Bhangra indian Jingle Bells balle balle Merry Christmas">
        <img src="http://graph.facebook.com/1236870349/picture">
    </a>

    <div class="popover fade left in" style="top: 831px; left: 805.61669921875px; display: block;">
    <div class="arrow"></div>
    <div class="popover-inner">
        <h3 class="popover-title">Bhangra indian Jingle Bells balle balle Merry Christmas</h3>
        <div class="popover-content">
            <p><a href="/social/2lPdXV1KO4s/Bhangra indian Jingle Bells balle balle Merry Christmas"><img src="http://i4.ytimg.com/vi/2lPdXV1KO4s/hqdefault.jpg"></a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It seem like you now have to prevent the default behavior of the link because they added the option to popup the popover on hover/focus. Right now the link will activate and since the href is pointing to "#" it will bring you to the top of the page. Before in older versions, it used to prevent this default automatically.

Your javascript code should look something like this:

```
<script>
$("a[rel=popover]")
    .popover()
    .click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
     });
 </script>
```

With html like this

```
<a href="#" 
   class="btn btn-large btn-danger" 
   rel="popover" 
   data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. right?" 
   data-original-title="A Title">
     Click to toggle popover
 </a>
```

Here is a working JSfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/hajpoj/KPU47/7/

**Edit:** Alternatively you could use a div instead of a anchor tag and not have to do the whole prevent default thing.

```
<div 
   class="btn btn-large btn-danger popover-link"
   data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. right?"
   data-original-title="A Title">Click to toggle popover
</div>​

<script>
    $(".popover-link").popover();
</script>
```

Answer (score 12):

I have encountered exactly the same issue with the popover and it was enough to replace href="#" with href="javascript://".

Comment: @PixelGraph It does the job, but trying to understand why... This seems a little hacky?

Comment: It just prevents the default behavior of the browser by executing the provided js code, in a more simple way than the one with jquery click event. It might look hacky but in my opinion it is not at all.

Answer (score 2):

Just use this code. No extra `div`, `class` or whatever else needed.

```
$("a[data-toggle=popover]").popover().click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to what @hajpoj said, except it's the order that matters. As well, this is a nicer way to do it because you can dynamically add `.popover` elements to the page and it will continue to work.

```js
$('body').on('click', 'a[rel=popover]', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  return;
}).popover({
  selector: 'a[rel=popover]'
});
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac metus nisi. Nulla facilisi. In bibendum ultricies ultrices. Pellentesque sagittis, purus non venenatis mollis, nulla risus fermentum nisi, eget vulputate nulla felis nec mi. Donec rutrum
  nisi sed turpis pulvinar non fermentum risus fringilla. Ut sapien tellus, venenatis sit amet venenatis quis, rhoncus et nulla. Nam augue nisl, consequat vitae convallis sit amet, egestas at ante. Aliquam fringilla viverra porttitor.
</p>
<p>
  Aliquam ornare suscipit posuere. Phasellus ac turpis vitae elit sollicitudin condimentum. Duis massa purus, porttitor sed cursus eu, lacinia at velit. Nam ullamcorper mi ac sapien pretium mollis. Curabitur ante elit, euismod eget elementum condimentum,
  semper a dui. Pellentesque luctus orci elit, ut mattis dolor. Quisque semper nisl eu enim cursus consectetur a in elit. Phasellus faucibus gravida elit vel lobortis. Donec vitae nisi ut libero sollicitudin sodales pretium at purus. Praesent vulputate
  dignissim pulvinar. Nunc sit amet mauris a arcu pulvinar aliquam. Vivamus varius nisl elementum dolor posuere volutpat. Maecenas sed lectus tortor. Aenean sit amet dapibus arcu.
</p>
<p>
  Aliquam posuere sagittis viverra. Aenean velit lorem, vehicula quis viverra vel, porttitor at est. Curabitur at molestie tortor. Quisque at justo eu lacus accumsan aliquam. Ut auctor dui et augue posuere eleifend. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nunc enim enim,
  ullamcorper at scelerisque eu, cursus sit amet lectus. Quisque ac augue erat, vitae tempus diam. Nunc at erat pulvinar lectus vestibulum congue. Vivamus lorem leo, tristique non tempus a, laoreet sit amet ligula. Maecenas tristique vulputate ante, nec
  aliquet enim lobortis vel. Morbi convallis quam sed tellus consectetur hendrerit. Vestibulum vel elit at risus tempor posuere. Vivamus ultricies molestie feugiat. Sed iaculis eros massa. Mauris ac nunc orci.
</p>
<p>
  Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque volutpat iaculis tortor vel hendrerit. Cras sapien orci, fermentum id molestie vel, feugiat in tortor. Quisque vitae felis non tellus volutpat aliquet luctus sit amet felis. Pellentesque gravida tempus turpis, eu lobortis
  eros rutrum eu. In malesuada ultrices leo, eu pretium quam molestie quis. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Cras ac risus eros. Ut posuere lobortis magna, at blandit mauris tristique ut. Suspendisse
  volutpat mollis elit non sagittis. Nam in dictum felis. Maecenas dolor turpis, aliquet vel vestibulum vel, hendrerit non tortor. In pharetra nulla nec arcu rutrum ut commodo tortor facilisis. Curabitur congue feugiat felis vel sollicitudin. Proin in
  mollis dolor. Nulla mattis, turpis vestibulum vehicula blandit, tortor neque posuere diam, sed tempus neque odio id diam.
</p>
<p>
  Vestibulum non quam et elit consequat pellentesque sed at leo. Pellentesque iaculis, purus sit amet cursus imperdiet, orci mi consectetur sapien, sed sodales dui lectus vel enim. Curabitur ac arcu at lectus dictum luctus. Duis et aliquet eros. Suspendisse
  mi mi, porta at elementum pulvinar, pulvinar eu elit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce molestie mollis neque, et elementum odio dapibus sed. Nulla blandit sollicitudin quam semper dictum.
  Pellentesque rutrum rhoncus lacus et facilisis. Sed mattis felis sit amet neque viverra ullamcorper. Fusce volutpat quam scelerisque nisi dignissim vel congue nulla sodales.
</p>


<a href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-danger" rel="popover" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. right?" data-original-title="A Title">
    Click to toggle popover
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

add onclick="return false;" to your link; it prevents the browser from following the "#" link: